# Avoid serialize intermediate tag

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I want remove nResult tag that is displayed to following. I tried changing DataContract by MessageContract, with IsWrapped = false like is displayed in the link [Avoid "...Response" tag in wcf soap message](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/351048c9-a750-4592-bb66-dd046af8c8c7/avoid-response-tag-in-wcf-soap-message?forum=wcf), but does not work.

```
<nResponse xmlns="https://example.com/">
     <nResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <error>
           <Code>1</Code>
           <Message>User/Password mismatch</Message>
           <MessageUser>User/Password mismatch</MessageUser>
        </error>
     </nResult>
     <id>1234567890</id>
</nResponse>



[MessageContract(WrapperName = "nResponse")]
public class Response
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 2)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1, Name = "nResult", Namespace = "https://example.com/")]
    public Result result = new Result();
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "https://example.com/")]
public class Result
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string signonResult { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string controlVersion { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public Nullable<int> recordCount { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<record> resultSetName = new List<record>();
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public Error error = new Error();
}
```